# Find where headers are being added to Ajax Request

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers, request-headers

I am trying to recreate an HTTP request through Python Requests but it looks like there are headers being added to the Ajax Request on the page that is validated server-side.

[Here](https://reg.usps.com/portal/login) is the website I am trying to login to.

I was able to find the code that sends the POST request:

```
var b = "/entreg/json/AuthenticateAction";
var a;
var c = {
    username: d.username,
    password: d.password,
    newPassword: d.newPassword,
    retypeNewPassword: d.retypeNewPassword
};
$.ajax({
    url: b,
    cache: false,
    type: "post",
    data: $("#loginForm").serialize()
})
```

Even when I run this code by itself, it sends the request and adds the headers (all prefixed with `X-jFuguZWB-`). It looks like there is some obfuscated code that runs something like `$.ajaxSetup({headers: {"X-jFuguZWB-Z": "test-value"}})` to attach that header to all requests.

My question is, which part of [the page](https://reg.usps.com/portal/login) is adding these headers and is there any way to recreate the headers when I make my own POST request via Python?

I did find some obfuscated javascript in the `<!-- Google Tag Manager -->` section of the page but I am unable to tell what it is doing.